# Unable to update a document using save()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a NodeJS project. I am using express and mongoose. I am trying to update a document in MongoDB but updates are not showing up. Also, there is no error as the page is getting redirected  as per res.redirect('/content/contnet-view/'+id)

```
router.post('/posthere', function(req, res){
  const { id, Status, ModuleIndex, ItemIndex } = req.body;
   Content.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, foundContent){
   
if(err){
console.log(err);
res.status(500).send();
}else{
if(!foundEnroll){
res.status(404).send();
}else{
if(id){
  foundContent.ContentData.ContentM[ModuleIndex].ContentI[ItemIndex].Status = Status;
}
foundContent.save(function(err, updateContent){

  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }else{
      
      
    res.redirect('/content/contnet-view/'+id) 
  }
})}}
  })})
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are using express js.. then why not `router.put` for update?

Answer (score 0):

Using findByIdAndUpdate is better approach but in this case, mongoose save function returns a promise object.
If `save()` succeeds, the promise resolves to the document that was saved

```
doc.save().then(savedDoc => {
       savedDoc === doc; // true
       });
```

You need to use thenable chain approach to handle async function instead of callback

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with misconfigured Schema. matching it with the Document format fixed it.