# Why mongoose is not awaiting for await new MODEL.save()

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have 2 servers and one of these is work fine, but second (modified variant of first) is not

`This is **not works**:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const newBriefAppeal = await new BriefAppeal(req.body);
  let appealId;
  let target;
  let goals;
  let brand;
  let ***;
  try {
    const savedBriefAppeal = await newBriefAppeal.save(function (err, appeal) {
      appealId = appeal.id;
      target = appeal.step01target;
      goals = appeal.step02goals;
      brand = appeal.step03brand;
      *** = appeal.***
    });
    res.status(200).json(savedBriefAppeal);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

`
and i got error

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

`but this variant in my similar project works fine:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const newAppeal = await new Appeal(req.body);
  let appealId;
  let name;
  let email;
  let phone;
  let subject;
  let message;
  let attachments = [];
  try {
    const savedAppeal = await newAppeal.save(function (err, appeal) {
      appealId = appeal.id;
      name = appeal.name;
      email = appeal.email;
      phone = appeal.phone;
      subject = appeal.subject;
      message = appeal.text;
      attachments = appeal.appealAttach.map((attachment) => ({
        filename: attachment,
        path: "./uploads/media/mailAttachments/" + attachment,
      }));
    });
    res.status(200).json(savedAppeal);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Where's i'm wrong and why my appeal is undefined ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987335/unable-to-update-a-document-using-save

Comment: The variant doesn't work fine either, though, mind.

Comment: workable variant is works fine on two projects for a months, huh, but at third time is not right on start of developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing in a callback. As it says in [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save), `save` only returns a promise when you **don't** pass in a callback:

> **Returns:**
>
> ...Returns `undefined` if used with callback or a Promise otherwise.

**Either** use the old-style callback signature **or** use the promise feature.

Comment: I think I've seen this issue before but I'm not finding a duplicate. Anyone have one? I can delete the above if there's a good answer elsewhere already.